# Is there a handle for the homepage?

Tags: local.xml

I am trying to get a hero carousel on my homepage that I also want at the bottom of some other pages, like my search results page. The content is the same, but the div it is wrapped in needs different Foundation grid classes for each page.

So, I made a core/template `phtml` file for each of the locations and I want to call it in to, and they are working. Each of those has a div with the grid classes I need and inside it has `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('heroCarousel') ?>` from a third core/template `phtml` file.

I know I need to identify this last phtml template with `as=""`, and I have done this kind of thing once before, for example, for the search results page using this code:

```
<catalogsearch_result_index>
     <block type="cms/block" name="full_width" as="full_width">
         <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>full_width_static_block</block_id></action>
     </block>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

How can I do the same for the homepage? I have to identify the .phtml template with `as=""` before I can call it in with `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('heroCarousel') ?>`, right? If that is so, what is the handle for doing this on the homepage?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you install http://www.mgt-commerce.com/magento-developer-toolbar.html  . This is an extension that is very helpfully when learning magento

Comment: @DannyDevNz Thanks, I installed it. It's only appearing in the admin. Is that right?

Comment: Figured it out. I put it in the default theme and not my theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with below

```
<cms_index_index>    

 <block type="cms/block" name="full_width" as="full_width">
         <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>full_width_static_block</block_id></action>
     </block>

</cms_index_index>
```

if you wish to call it within in conten part you can use like

```
 <cms_index_index>    
   <reference name="content">    
     <block type="cms/block" name="full_width" as="full_width">
             <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>full_width_static_block</block_id></action>
         </block>
   </reference> 
    </cms_index_index>
```

or if you need to make your block as root block then you can use it.

```
 <cms_index_index>    
   <reference name="root">
     <block type="cms/block" name="full_width" as="full_width">
             <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>full_width_static_block</block_id></action>
         </block>
   </reference> 
    </cms_index_index>
```

you can change or edit to give any parent `reference` tag before your `block` tag

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain the last part of your comment once more? I'm not following completely.

Comment: @b_d_m_p, see my updates.hope you can now understand more and will help you.

Comment: Thank you again. I see now. Just out of curiosity, if the html is called in with `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('full_width') ?>`, and that is in the phtml file, doesn't that give the location? Why do the xml files require reference location? Wouldn't the system make more sense if the block template was identified with `as=""`, and then could be called in with `getChildHtml` anywhere, in any phtml file? I'm just trying to wrap my head around that logic. It seems redundant, no?

Comment: i will be happy. if i could give you correct answer. More or less its design pattern followed by magento. you can refer this http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/magento-design-terminologies4 to understand more on this. see next page as well.

Comment: I've read the docs a bunch, but I guess it hasn't clicked for me yet. Thanks a lot. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: I marked it as correct. I can't upvote yet. I will when I can.